# HTML Formatting using Slack Web API

Tags: html, asp.net-web-api, slack-api

So we are implementing the Slack chat.postMessage API function in an application. It looks like this:

https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage?token=XXXXXXX&channel=XXXXXXX&text=hello&pretty=1

The text you want to send in the message would replace the "hello" in this URL. Is it possible to use this API call to send that message in HTML instead of in plain text? For example if you want to send

- test

Then the API sends the literal HTML < ul >< li >... etc

Any way we could send this so it would appear like it should?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Slack doesn't support HTML for formatting messages. The documentation for message formatting is here: https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting.